# android Admob 6 few general questions

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to integrate admob 6 with my app and having some issues-questions.

At first i couldnt make my app to compile with the new admob 6. I had

```
configchanges="keyboard|keyboardhidden|orientation"
```

logcat was complaining about missing attributes. so, configchanges became:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Then, I couldnt compile it! Cause i had my target build set for android 1.6. I managed to compile it by changing the target build to the latest sdk version i have installed: 4.0.3.

But here is the thing now, I cannot deploy my application to any emulator other than the one that has android 4.0.3 installed! To be specific, i have 5-6 emulators all with different android version and screen sizes for testing. I have emulator with android 1.6, 2.2, galaxy tab, android 4.0.3 etc...but now I can only see the android 4.0.3!

I want my app to be able to run on android 1.6 and older!
after reading a lot i saw :minsdkVersion and targetsdkversion.
minsdkversion is set to 4 and targetsdkversion to 12!

but still. I can only deploy to android 4.0.3 emulator.
what gives??
how can i test my app on previous versions????

any help please?

Comment: Have you tried putting it on a 1.6 emulator?  Eclipse unfortunately puts a red "X" next to emulators that are lower than the version you're compiling against, but that shouldn't affect your ability to run it on those emulators.

Comment: thats the weird thing. I cannot see any emulator except the one that has 4.0.3 installed!!! did i do something wrong???!

Comment: Is the 1.6 emulator running?  If so, sometimes Eclipse doesn't pick it up.  Try running `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server` on the command line, and Eclipse should pick up any emulators that are running but were disconnected.

Comment: I still havent tried what you said, but I managed to make it work by going to the options and setting the emulator from automatic to manual. After that eclipsed picked up the emulators with the red "X" and manually selecting the emulators. WIll try your way also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by setting the emulator to manual selection.
evem though there is a red X it deploys.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different emulators to test different devices. As you have noticed you should set targetSDKVersion to 12 or more in order to compile. In order to accommodate older devices with older android version, you can set minSDKVersion to whatever you prefer.